# How can i write doc comments for test and make a report with typedoc?

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, typedoc

I need to write doc comments for my test and then generate the documentation in a HTML file. I successfully generate the documentation with typedoc but only for my class and method and not for my test. My question is: how can I write doc comments for my test?

For my test I use testcafe. I have always successfully generated the report.

/** 
* test license02  */ <-- this block comment is not generated

test('LICENSE-02', async t => {

...

});

I need to generate the doc comment for my test but for now only the method and class are documented.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I can see a similar question in the TypeDoc repository: https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/821. TypeDoc creates documentation only for TypeScript declarations, e.g. for namespaces, classes, methods, properties, functions, variables, constants. TestCafe's tests are not declarations, they are just `test` function calls, so doc comments above them are ignored.

You can declare a test body as a function and apply a doc comment to it, for example:

```
/**
* test license02
* @category Test
* @param t TestCafe test controller
*/
async function test_license02 (t: TestController): Promise<void> {
    // ...
}
test('LICENSE-02', test_license02);
```